# Symfony2 - Is basic authentication configuration required for traditional login form?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, basic-authentication

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html) seems to suggest that both `http_basic:` and `form_login:` should be configured in `security.yml` to implement a traditional login form.

But, isn't the purpose of a login form to replace the http basic authentication? Does `http_basic:` really have to be configured? If yes, why? If not, can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony Security has a variety of options to authenticate the user and the documentation shows two of them – and that you can use more than one at the same time.

But you don’t have to do that. **You can remove `http_basic`.**